# Connect imported nodes (CSV LOAD) to a general group

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I was trying to build a query that will solve this tasks:

1. Import a CSV with the format "user","group" to Neo4J
2. Generate for each USER a node - avoid duplicates
3. Generate for each GROUP a node - avoid duplicates
4. Connect the node USER to the imported GROUP
5. Finally connect every imported GROUP to a MAINGROUP

I have written the query like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:.....csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (u:User { name: csvLine[0]})
MERGE (g:Group { name: csvLine[1]}) 
MERGE (u)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g)
MERGE (g)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(m:Group {name: "MAINGROUP"})
```

So far this works as I get every User and every Group and they are connected.

Problem: All my GROUPs do not have a relationship to a single Node (MAINGROUP) but each GROUP has a relationsship to a duplicate MAINGROUP - means for every GROUP my query seems to generate a duplicate new MAINGROUP (although I was hoping MERGE would prevent this) so I end up with as many nodes MAINGROUP as I have imported GROUPs.

How do I need to alter the query to get the desired graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common gotcha of using `MERGE`.   [See the docs here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html).

When you use `MERGE` on a pattern, it creates everything if the entire pattern didn't already exist, not just the portions of the pattern that didn't already exist.

What you should be doing is using `MERGE` once to find/create `(m:Group {name: "MAINGROUP"})` and then `MERGE` just the new relationship.   Because MERGE is matching on the whole pattern `(g)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(m:Group {name: "MAINGROUP"})` and it doesn't exist, it's re-creating the main group every time.

So you might want to do this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:.....csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (u:User { name: csvLine[0]})
MERGE (g:Group { name: csvLine[1]}) 
MERGE (u)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g)
MERGE (m:Group {name: "MAINGROUP"})
MERGE (g)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(m)
```

The last two lines are different.

This way of getting tripped up with MERGE is unfortunately really common.  :)

Comment: Ouch, thanks fur pushing me into the right direction, very appreciated!